# Set height of only one md-tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-material

This is actually pretty simple, I'm just looking for a way to set the height one `<md-tab>`'s content to `100%` in a modular way. For example, say I have the following:

```
<body>
    <md-content>
        <md-tabs>
          <md-tab label="Tab A">
            <div> I should be the full height of the available space. </div>
          </md-tab>
          <md-tab label="Tab 2">
            <div> I should just be big enough to fit this content </div>
          </md-tab>
        </md-tabs>
    </md-content>
</body>
```

I could easily get the desired effect with

```
md-tab-content#tab-content-0 div[md-tabs-template]{
    height: 100%
}
```

but then if I decide I want another tab before Tab A, it'll apply the style to the new tab instead of Tab A and then I have to manually change the selector to fix it. Is there a way to accomplish this without making a new directive, i.e. it would ideally just be editing the html and css.

UPDATE: Just found out I can use sass as of last night, so sass away if that helps.

EDIT: Here's a couple of pictures of what I want to accomplish, the red line indicates the active tab and the blue background indicates the area taken up by the div; the whole thing is the body of the html.

[image]

[image]

EDIT 2: Here's a codepen I made by tweaking an angular material demo: http://codepen.io/ocket8888/pen/YWxGGW. The only attempt at a solution I had was to attempt to use parent selectors, which are deprecated/unimplemented in virtually every browser so I didn't include it.

Comment: Can you draw a quick image of what kind of layout you are shooting for?  I can't visualize it with your description.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please edit to describe the problem in more detail and explain how your solution doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: Better yet, make a codepen or jsfiddle for us! ;)

Comment: Took me a bit, I'm not an artist.

Comment: *but then if I decide I want another tab before Tab A, then I have to manually change the selector.* So you're trying to change the CSS of the 1st item, regardless of what it's actually called?

Comment: Not necessarily the 1st, just specifically Tab A. See, if I use the `tab-content-<index>` data then it'll always apply the style to the tab in that position, when I want it to always apply the style to Tab A.

Comment: Only way I see to get this done would use a JavaScript mutation observer and a jQuery content selector -- really hit it with "the jQuery stick." Those shenanigans probably fall under your "cheating" label, but me know if you'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: I'm expressly forbidden to edit css from javascript, and since I'm using angular it's generally considered bad form to use jQuery since their paradigms differ so heavily. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Will the label stay consistent? If so I'm pretty sure you can do

```
[label="Tab 2"] div{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This won't work, because when angular renders the `md-tabs` it turns it into an `ng-repeat="(index, tab) in $mdTabsCtrl.tabs"` which cranks out `md-tab-content`'s that don't have labels.

tl;dr: the labels belong to the tab headings but don't appear on the elements that make up the tab contents.

Comment: Can you paste the compiled HTML to reference? As long as there are any properties at all on the output, you should be able to target them with [key="value"] in the CSS

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/9ec84a057c9c11c5821dff3ffe7478ee.png < that's the actual html I'm working with. In this case the specific tag I need to style is the `md-tab-content` with `id="tab-content-14"`'s child, seen here: https://i.gyazo.com/130e75ea4506517335950d187e2acb79.png . I'm not going to add this to my question because it doesn't represent a MCVE (working on a codepen atm)

Comment: Hmmm, I'm assuming the 14 gets generated and isn't static, so that's no good as a selector. Aside from that, I don't see anything that you can use as a target, unfortunately :(

Comment: Yeah, even if it was static that's not very maintainable because it limits my ability to rearrange and add tabs.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking to just target the first tab for 100%... all others should take auto which is probably what the parent is set to:

```
.md-tabs .md-tab:first-child {
    height: 100%
}
```

Not sure if those selectors match up to your final HTML, but you should get the idea with targeting ":first-child"

Comment: No, see I want to apply a style to Tab A that will persist if its position changes. I'll edit my question to make that more clear.